Mat select auto select in Angular 16
I am using angular 16, in below code my form Control is selectedClassesSlotsByUser that default value is 10 that's why i am getting 10 by default selected in my mat-select tag, the problem occurs when i choose option select manually and open a model which returns a value after closing,i have tried changing value of form control even i created a new form control when i get the returned value from mat dialogue....this is a code given below
<div class="row" *ngIf="slotDetails.classDetails.classType === 'Tutoring' && slotsInBatchConstant > 10">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 ">
                                    <mat-select (selectionChange)="calculatePrice()" class="py-2 selected-classes col-3" [formControl]="selectedClassesSlotsByUser">
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let class of selectedoptionArray" [value]="class">
                                            {{ class }} classes selected
                                        </mat-option>
                                        <mat-option class="bg-selected" (click)="selectManually($event)">Select Manually</mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

and this is i am handling response of mat dialogue in formcontrol
selectManually(event : Event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    const countControl = this.dialogctrl.open(CountComponentComponent,{
      closeOnNavigation : true,
      maxHeight : '60vh',
      maxWidth : '500px',
      data : {
        minClass : 10,
        maxClass : this.slotsInBatchConstant
      }
    })

    countControl.afterClosed().subscribe((result)=>{
      this.selectedClassesSlotsByUser = new FormControl(result);
      this.calculatePrice()
    })
  }```

